# how to reference a store variable inside a value.sync statement in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Ok, so I have a Vuex store that manages dropdown content on my page. The page I'm currently working on has two sets of three identical dropdowns that should behave exactly the same. One on a modal and the other one on the main page. So what I did is this:

```
this.$store.commit('setModule', 'manageSchedules');
this.$store.commit('setModule', 'manageSchedulesModale');
```

Each store has the following:

```
// These are arrays with the lists' content
sites
Profiles
Employees 

//These are the actual value of each of my list

CurrentSite
CurrentProfile
CurrentEmployee
```

My problem is that I'd like the value of my list to by synched with the corresponding "currentXXX" of my vuex store. Normally, I'd go with something like:

```
:value.sync="currentXXX"
```

However, I can't find anywhere how exactly to reference the store in a value.sync statement. Could anyone help me?

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/using-vuex-with-prop-sync/14430/4

Comment: You just need a computed property with a getter and a setter pointing to your store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Ricky was right, using a computed property with getter and setter worked perfectly and his link provided me with all the info I needed. In essence here's what I now have:

```
<template lang="pug">
    .modal(v-if="popupShown", style="display:block", v-on:click="hideModalSafe")
        .modal-dialog.modal-lg(v-on:keydown.enter="syncSchedule()")
            .modal-content
                h3.modal-header {{moment(currentSchedule.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}}
                    button.close(type="button",v-on:click="popupShown=false") &times;
                .modal-body
                    .row
                        .col.form-group
                            label(for="schedule-start") {{__('Start')}}
                            k-input-time(:date.sync="currentSchedule.start")
                        .col.form-group
                            label(for="schedule-end") {{__('End')}}
                            k-input-time(:date.sync="currentSchedule.end")
                        .col.form-group
                            label(for="schedule-pause") {{__('Pause')}}
                            k-input-minutes(:minutes.sync="currentSchedule.pause")
                    .row
                        .col.form-group
                            label(for="schedule-site-id") {{__('Site')}}
                            k-combobox(model="modSites", context="selection", 
                            :value.sync="currentSiteMod")
                        .col.form-group
                            label(for="schedule-profile-id") {{__('Profile')}}
                            k-combobox(model="modProfiles", context="selection", 
                            :value.sync="currentProfileMod")
                        .col.form-group
                            label(for="schedule-employee-id") {{__('Employee')}}
                            k-combobox(model="modEmployees", context="selection", 
                            :value.sync="currentEmployeeMod")
                .modal-footer
                    .btn.btn-danger.mr-auto(v-on:click="deleteSchedule()")
                        k-icon(icon="delete")     
                        |  {{__('Remove')}}
                    .btn.btn-primary(v-on:click="syncSchedule()", tabindex="0") {{__('Save')}}
</template>


export default {
    ......
    computed:{
        currentSiteMod:{
            get(){
                return this.$store.state.manageSchedulesModale.currentSite;
            },
            set(value){
                this.$store.dispatch("manageSchedulesModale/updateCurrentSite", value);
            }
        },
        currentProfileMod:{
            get(){
                return this.$store.state.manageSchedulesModale.currentProfile;
            },
            set(value){
                this.$store.dispatch("manageSchedulesModale/updateCurrentProfile", value);
            }
        },
        currentEmployeeMod: {
            get(){
                return this.$store.state.manageSchedulesModale.currentEmployee;
            },
            set(value){
                this.$store.dispatch("manageSchedulesModale/updateCurrentEmployee", value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once again, Vue.js actually impressed me with its magic. Before going with computed properties, I got tangled in a slew of ajax calls and promises that kept going back and forth, producing inconsistent results. Now, the store's value gets updated perfectly and the lists react accordingly without me having to worry about an insane amount of parameters.

Anyway, there's probably a few things I didn't do right. I know I probably should have defined getters instead of accessing the property directly, but as it stands, it works and my client's happy (and so am I).